# Why is there no menu bar in Keynote for iOS?

Tags: ios, keynote

Keynote for iOS doesn't show a menu bar, only buttons.

Is there a possibility to show a menu bar ?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you recently switch from Windows to Mac?

Comment: And if my answer did not answer the problem, you need to explain further what the problem is. Screenshots are nice too, and you can upload them right into Stack Exchange when writing your post.

Comment: No. I should probably have added that I got an iPad 2 for Christmas and downloaded keynote so I could prepare a presentation for college. When I watched how-to keynote videos, there was a menu on top. Is the menu ononly on keynote for laptops but not iPads?

Comment: So this is on Keynote for iOS? It would have been nice to know that earlier.

Comment: Sorry. I'm just learning.

Answer (score 1):

iOS applications have no menus.

Menus are a feature of OS X applications.